# Does Saptpadi and other rituals happen in case of Swamvar Vivah?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, marriage

In case a man won a girl in the Swamvara or the girl chooses the boy . Does , Saptapadi and other fire rituals happen after it to get the marriage solemnized or

Does the marriage deemed to be done once the girl chooses the man (garlands the man) in the Swamvara?

Many marriages in Purans happend in Swamvara way , what happened in those stories , Did Vedic rituals like - Kanya-Daan etc happened after Swamvara ?

Comment: Yes they do. At least they did so in the Ramayana.